# Is there some way to cause VS Build to fail on JS Hint errors using the WebEssentials plugin?

Tags: javascript, build, teamcity, jshint, web-essentials

I have my app throwing JSHint violations into the Error Output using "LintResultLocation": "Error" but the build still "succeeds" and doesn't give any indication that something is wrong unless you specifically go look at the Error Log.  I would like to cause a build Error that will be caught by our TeamCity build server. Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teamcity automatically fails a build if a process is exited with some error code. However if your process in not returning error code you can alternatively fail the build based on a search string in the logs. You can set a **Build Failure Condition** which will search for a specific text in the logs and fail the build if the text is found.

[image]

Comment: This will work to solve most of my problem. It still won't inform the developer before they push the change unless they happen to look at the error log, but as long as the build server catches it then it will at least be addressed. Thanks!